# PySide.QtCore.QCharがない。

Tags: python, qt

python3.5で`PySide.QtCore.__version__`　4.8.7を利用しています。
QTextObjectInterfaceの手続きに従おうとしたところ、
QtCore.QCharを利用するよう書いてあるのですが、リファレンスから
削除されたのか見当たりません。QChar.ObjectReplacementCharacter
を使いたいです。存在しないアトリビュートを利用しろと書いてある
ので厳しいです。また、pythonライブラリの
chrでもないようです。

Comment: �の事らしいです。これを代わりに使えばいいのだろうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PySideではUnicode文字を直接記述するとのことです。(参考: 本家「[i can not find QString in PySide 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626430/i-can-not-find-qstring-in-pyside-1-1-0)」)
ですので、`QChar`や`QString`を介して文字を扱わなくてもよいと思います。

なお、`QChar.ObjectReplacementCharacter`の値は0xfffcと[`QChar`のAPI文書](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#SpecialCharacter-enum)にあるので、直接指定してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: u"\uFFFC"で対応しました。はっきりとした文字が出て来ませんが、これしかないと思います。ありがとうございました。